# Why should I mount a secret or configmap in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, volumes, kubernetes-secrets

In kubernetes POD I have an option to mount a secret or a configmap as a volume mounted to the POD.  It would be difficult to access these files as environment variables. So why should I be doing it instead of using them as environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how the application expect to load the secret.

E.g. if the application expect to load an [SSL certificate file](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/https/ssl-certificate-format), it is possible to have the certificated as a file in a Secret and mount the Secret so that the application can read it as file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to always mount the secret or configmap. You can use them too set the environment variables as shown below

> ```
>       envFrom:
>       - configMapRef:
>           name: env-configmap
>       - secretRef:
>           name: env-secrets
> ```

However, there are situations  when you might want to mount them as files. For example:

1. You want to keep your nginx.conf decoupled from your docker image.
2. Put your SSL Certs (cert + private keys) in  secret to enable  SSL on  your web application